# Is there a cleaner or simpler way to achieve this in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say i have an oracle table that represents simple bank operations with this definition :

```
create table mytable(id_operation varchar(11),
                     operation_type varchar2(11),
                     amount number);
```

The table has the following data :

```
ID_OPERATION    OPERATION_TYPE  AMOUNT
1                credit          200
2                credit          150
```

For each operation i want to also select in a query  the debit version of it like so :

```
ID_OPERATION    OPERATION_TYPE  AMOUNT
1C              credit           200
1D              debit           -200
2C              credit           150
2D              debit           -150
```

Here's what i've tried :

```
select id_operation||'C' id_operation ,operation_type , amount
from mytable
union
select id_operation||'D' , 'debit', - amount
from mytable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `cross join`:

```
select t.id_operation || x.suffix as id_operation,
       coalesce(x.operation_type, t.operation_type) as operation_type,
       (t.amount * x.mult) as amount
from mytable t cross join
     (select 'C' as suffix, null as operation_type, 1 as mult from dual union all
      select 'D' as suffix, 'debit' as operation_type, -1 as mult from dual
     ) x
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `UNION` and that is the cleanest way of achieving it.

Also, You can use the `CONNECT BY` as follows:

```
SELECT
    ID_OPERATION || DECODE(LEVEL, 1, 'C', 'D') AS ID_OPERATION,
    DECODE(LEVEL, 1, OPERATION_TYPE, 'debit') AS OPERATION_TYPE,
    DECODE(LEVEL, 1, AMOUNT, - AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT
FROM MYTABLE
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! your query seems to work , although it brings me six records instead of four